# Use command for node position in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

I have a command setup to calculate the transformed location of a nodes point, because I want to center these nodes on top of rectangles which have been rotated. So instead of manually calculating the values using a calculator, I attempted to automate it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{physics}

\newcommand{\rotateX}[5]{\pgfmathparse{cos(#5)*(#1-#3)-sin(#5)*(#2-#4)+#3}\pgfmathresult}
\newcommand{\rotateY}[5]{\pgfmathparse{sin(#5)*(#1-#3)+cos(#5)*(#2-#4)+#4}\pgfmathresult}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    ...
    % Line 27
    \node at (\rotateX{-0.5}{3.5}{-2}{1}{40},\rotateY{-0.5}{3.5}{-2}{1}{40}) {$\mathcal{C}\left(\vb*{A}^\top\right)$};
    ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `\rotateX` command on its own works perfectly fine, yet I cannot use this output as the position for the node in my TikZpicture.

**Error I receive:**

```
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 27.

    <inserted text> 
                \fi 
    <*> main.tex
```

**What I would like (manually entered positions):**

```
\node at (-2.4579,3.87929) {$\mathcal{C}\left(\vb*{A}^\top\right)$};
```

(I added the gridlines and axes to show that it's at exactly (-2.4579,3.87929))
[image: Output]

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: that is why pgfmathparse separates calculation from returning the result. you need something that expands to the number so do the calculations first then just use the result macros

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to this @DavidCarlisle. What should I do then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove `\pgfmathparse` and `\pgfmathresult`, Ti*k*Z will parse the coordinates anyway.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{physics}
\newcommand{\rotateX}[5]{{cos(#5)*(#1-#3)-sin(#5)*(#2-#4)+#3}}
\newcommand{\rotateY}[5]{{sin(#5)*(#1-#3)+cos(#5)*(#2-#4)+#4}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    ...
    % Line 27
    \node at (\rotateX{-0.5}{3.5}{-2}{1}{40},\rotateY{-0.5}{3.5}{-2}{1}{40}) 
    {$\mathcal{C}\left(\vb*{A}^\top\right)$};
    ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Since you use the same arguments for x and y, you can just put them in one macro (if you really want to use macros).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{physics}
\newcommand{\rotateX}[5]{{cos(#5)*(#1-#3)-sin(#5)*(#2-#4)+#3}}
\newcommand{\rotateY}[5]{{sin(#5)*(#1-#3)+cos(#5)*(#2-#4)+#4}}
\newcommand{\rotateXY}[5]{(\rotateX{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5},\rotateY{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5})}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    ...
    % Line 27
    \node at \rotateXY{-0.5}{3.5}{-2}{1}{40}
    {$\mathcal{C}\left(\vb*{A}^\top\right)$};
    ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is much more concise! let me try

Comment: Thanks so much, works beautifully :)

Answer (score 3):

Please always post examples that can be used, this has undefined `\vb` but you need to separate the calculations from the arguments to `\node` which must expand to a number.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rotateX}[5]{\pgfmathparse{cos(#5)*(#1-#3)-sin(#5)*(#2-#4)+#3}\let\myX\pgfmathresult}
\newcommand{\rotateY}[5]{\pgfmathparse{sin(#5)*(#1-#3)+cos(#5)*(#2-#4)+#4}\let\myY\pgfmathresult}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    ...
    % Line 27
    \rotateX{-0.5}{3.5}{-2}{1}{40}%
    \rotateY{-0.5}{3.5}{-2}{1}{40}%
    \node at (\myX,\myY) {$\mathcal{C}\left(\vb*{A}^\top\right)$};
    ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document
```

Comment: it was the physics package sorry

Comment: thanks for the reply again though David! I assume I can reuse this method for multiple nodes, as the variable x and y will just get updated?

Comment: @Tarang74 yes...